# ffmpeg vs mediainfo for getting thumbnail and metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, mediainfo

I need to extract the metadata information from a video file as well as a thumbnail for that file.   For this I have tried ffmpeg and the metadata (such as duration, resolution, codecs, creation_time etc) is seen on the stdout. If I need to use these I should parse the stdout and extract the metadata I need.

I've also read about the MediaInfo utility which also delivers metadata. I'm not sure if it can deliver thumbnails. What I also know is that MediaInfo does not use ffmpeg under the hood.

I was wondering if anyone has a working knowledge of both ffmpeg and MediaInfo and with respect to the requirement I mentioned above, whether someone could suggest which of the two is a better suited.

Memory footprint comparison of the two would also be great.

Comment: In what context does this need to be achieved? In a Bash script, a C program, over the web?

Comment: I intend to invoke the program via C++ code and analyze the resulting output (emitted in the stdout for instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is neither ffmpeg nor mediainfo. Well, not the complete executables anyway.

ffmpeg is comprised of a series of libraries, including `libavformat`, which allows you to work with the multimedia container formats. [Using libavformat and libavcodec](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html) by Martin Böhme should give you a good introduction.

Comment: The link in the above comment has rotted.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the underlying libraries directly as indicated in other answers.

However, for sake of completeness should you persist in using a separate shell process instead, **don't parse FFmpeg's output**.  Instead, **use [FFprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)** which is the little-known tool specifically designed to complement FFmpeg and ease metadata extraction.

Also, generating thumbnails can be done with FFmpeg more or less like so:

```
ffmpeg [-ss 10] -i input.avi -vframes 1 -s 320x240 thumbnail.png
```

Adjust size to taste and use the optional `-ss` parameter to grab an image from some point other than the very beginning of the video.

Comment: Yeah. I'd checked out ffprobe earlier. But I would imagine I will have to turn back to ffmpeg for thumbnail extraction. And from what I've gathered so far, ffmpeg seems to be the only process for most kinds of operations on video / audio. Why I am a little sceptical about using ffprobe only for metadata is that I want to make sure I don't eat up too much space (I'm using these on a MIPS embedded device) Thanks for your input anyway

Comment: Happy to help.  At least on my install the ffprobe/ffmpeg binaries are relatively tiny compared to the underlying, shared, libraries, so including ffprobe as well might not be as costly as you imagine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know MediaInfo is opensource ([see here](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)) and its library can be used in a windows environment (it's a dll) from C++ or C#. No need to parse the output. It has documentation for developers and some samples.

I don't think it can extract thumbnails though.